# SharePoint calculated field based on another hidden field

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, spfield

In a production deployment we have a calculated field which is composed of a formula that references two other hidden fields.  This is simple concatenation with a little logic for determining version

```
=CONCATENATE(IF(_MajorVersion="","0",_MajorVersion),".",IF(_MinorVersion="","0",_MinorVersion))
```

A user inadvertently modified the formula in the datasheet view of the list and now the formula has become corrupted as shown below

```
=CONCATENATE(IF(#NAME="","0",#NAME),".",IF(#NAME="","0",#NAME))
```

If you replace this formula with the pre-corrupted version, it will not save, and gives the following error

`The formula refers to a column that does not exist.  Check the formula for spelling mistakes or change the non-existing column to an existing column.   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.UpdateField(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrXML) 
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.UpdateField(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrXML)`

The columns _MajorVersion and _MinorVersion do exist, but are hidden and defined as follows:

`<Field SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/3.0"
             ID="{GUID}"
             Name="_MajorVersion"
             StaticName="_MajorVersion"
             DisplayName="_MajorVersion"
             Group="ApplicationStuff"
             Type="Number"
             Required="FALSE"
             ReadOnly="FALSE"
             Sealed="FALSE"
             Hidden="TRUE"
             ShowInListSettings="FALSE"
             ShowInEditForm="FALSE"
             ShowInDisplayForm="FALSE"
             ShowInNewForm="FALSE" />`

I know it is possible to deploy a feature which will make these columns visible, fix the problem, and then re-hide them.  However, there is a **lot** of red-tape to make that happen.  Anyone know of a way to do this without deploying code?  I also considered re-creating the list, but there are thousands of SPListItems in this list.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unhide the fields (using some kind of utility, very simple to write), save the formula and hide back. But I think you should probably fill the calculated field in some other fashion, such as SPD workflow or event receiver.